Синонимизировать метки [nlp] и [естественный-язык]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

nlp (98 вопросов) описание есть
естественный-язык (17 вопросов) нет описания

Основная - естественный-язык (она на русском).

Готово!
Вливание "естественный язык" -> "nlp":
updating post history, 19 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 17 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 13 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'естественный-язык': [естественный-язык] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 112
tag remapping of [nlp] and [естественный-язык] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym естественный-язык -> nlp was approved!

Изменено направление синонимизации "nlp" -> "естественный язык":
updating post history, 135 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 112 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'естественный-язык' doesn't exist, renaming 'nlp' to 'естественный-язык'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [естественный-язык] and [nlp] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
11 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
4 tracked tag badges were remapped!


Хм... Как-то странно вышло.

@Зонтик предлагаю подождать, вероятно кеширование. Но вполне может быть и баг.

Может быть. Кстати, если нажимаю на [tag:естественный-язык], то либо перекидывает на [tag:nlp], либо вообще 404, если отсюда переходить.

@Зонтик похоже, что всё же баг. Поведение как уже описывал в феврале (см. последний абзац)

@Зонтик хотя вот сейчас починилось (значит, кеш).
